# FactoryGirl producing validation errors in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Ultimately, I am trying to use FactoryGirl to create an instance of an object that has an association through a join model. Here's my standard example of a `has_many :through`.

```
class Partition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :configs, through: :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partition
  belongs_to :config 
end

class Config < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :partitions, through: :lists
end
```

In my specs, I am doing this:

```
config = FactoryGirl.create(:config)
partition = FactoryGirl.create(:partition, configs: [config])
```

The line to create the partition is failing with, `Validation failed: Lists is invalid`. And I believe the reason is that it's creating things out of order. Here's my validation it's referring to:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :partition_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :config_id }
end
```

**Important Note: This seems to work great in Rails 3. I am trying to upgrade our application to Rails 4 and it's failing in Rails 4.**

I can make it work if I change the Factories to be:

```
config = FactoryGirl.create(:config)
partition = FactoryGirl.build(:partition, configs: [config])
partitions.save
```

Then everything seems to work great, but that's not what I want to do. I have read that in my factory I can do something like this:

```
factory :partition do |partition|  
  ...
  partition.after_create do |p|  
    p.configs << :config # Does not work, see update below
  end  
end
```

But I would like to pass in my config to my factory like I do above instead if possible.

So to reiterate my question: **How can I use FactoryGirl to create an object with as `has_many through:` relationship in Rails 4?**

**Update**

If I change my factory to have this:

```
factory :partition do
  ...
  after(:create) do |p|
    p.build_configurations << FactoryGirl.create(:tcid)
  end
end
```

Then, the test will pass only if I change my factory create to be:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:partition)
```

But my desired goal is:

```
config = # Get an instance of a Config
FactoryGirl.create(:partition, configs: [config])
```

**Update 2**

It seems that you **CAN** create Factories just like I want to above, but I think the timing must be off. If I remove the validations from my `List`, the `Partition` factory works just fine when I pass in `configs: [config]`.

It seems like the Factory is trying to save the lists (where the validations are) before saving the configs? Thoughts?

Comment: For whoever voted this question down, please let me know what I can do to improve the question if you don't think it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding `inverse_of` to your join table should solve the problem. Use it like this:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partition, inverse_of: :lists
  belongs_to :config, inverse_of: :lists
end
```

Comment: I gave that a shot but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Would about this?

```
factory :partition do
  # partition init goes here...

  after(:create) do |partition, evaluator|
    config = create :config
    list = create :list, partition: partition, config: config
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this, so you will have to give it a shot and see if it works for you.  The concept is to create the config record first, then the list item after that.

With the evaluator you could allow yourself to pass in a custom config as well that will be used instead of the default config in your Config factory, like so:

```
factory :partition do
  # partition init goes here...

  transient do
    custom_config: false
  end

  after(:create) do |partition, evaluator|
    if evaluator.custom_config
      config = custom_config
    else
      config = create :config
    end
    list = create :list, partition: partition, config: config
  end
end
```

Which would enable you to something like this:

```
config = # Some custom built config
partition = FactoryGirl.create(:partition, custom_config: config)
```

Transient properties are great for after creates, I have used them much, and once you get them, you will love the versatility they give you.

Comment: Although I think this might work, I don't really like the work around. Do you know what changed between Rails 3 and 4 for FactoryGirl to save things in a different order? See my latest updates :)